# Custom proxy creation for entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core in my application.

I do not want to use lazy loading. But I do want to throw an exception when a navigational property is accessed, which has not been loaded with `Include()` by the query.

It feels very close to what the lazy loading proxy actually does, but looking at the source code, it's using a lot of interfaces marked as "Internal".

Is there a supported way of generating custom proxies for this scenario?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me, why would you want to throw an exception?

Comment: @DavidG I want it to be obvious when some code makes a bad assumption about what was loaded. Today, that would cause a null reference exception, or worse, the code would assume that no references exist.

Comment: @mortenbock While I can see the use-case, still it has the same drawback as the lazy loading - how the external code will know if the navigation property is loaded or not in order to access it or not? Anyway, I guess you can use the standard lazy loading proxies support, but replace the `ILazyLoader` service with your own implementation which throws in places where the standard service implementation does actual loading.